# Does a function sequence decreasing monotonically to 0 converge uniformly?

Tags: general-topology, functions

Suppose $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous function$f_n:S\to \mathbb{R}$ where $S\subset \mathbb{R}$ and $S$ is compact. Suppose for $\{f_n(x)\}$ monotonic decreasing to zero for any $x\in S$. Is $\{f_n\}$ uniformly converge to $ 0$? I know all the definition of convergence and uniformly convergence and compact but still not sure how to start or prove it

Comment: See also [$f_1,f_2,\dots$ continuous on $[0,1]$ s.t $f_1 \geq f_2\geq \cdots$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/121603)

Comment: Hmm. I didn't see that when I searched for Dini's theorem prior to answering. Though I now realize that I would have gotten more relevant hits if I had used quotes.

Comment: Anyhow, to improve the chances of someone finding this one, I edited the title of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is known as [Dini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem).